# Simple code giving C++ errors C4430 and C2143

Tags: c++

In one of my projects, this code compiles without issue.

But in another project **using the same files**, it does not compile. I'm using VS2012 and the C/C++ Properties are identical between the two projects. I've searched here but couldn't find anything. Any help is appreciated!

Header file:

```
#include <vector>

extern void split(const wstring &s, WCHAR c, vector<wstring>& v);
```

C++ file:

```
void split(const wstring& s, WCHAR c, vector<wstring>& v) 
{
    string::size_type i = 0;
    string::size_type j = s.find(c);

    while (j != string::npos) {
    v.push_back(s.substr(i, j-i));
    i = ++j;
    j = s.find(c, j);

    if (j == string::npos)
       v.push_back(s.substr(i, s.length()));
   }
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
wstring csToken;
vector<wstring> vProductVersion;
TCHAR *sProductVersion = tcalloc(64);
StringCchCopy(sProductVersion,64,L"3.3.422");

// Put the string into a vector array.
csToken.assign(sProductVersion);
split(csToken, '.', vProductVersion);
```

Here are the errors the compiler generates:

```
1>c:\\projects\\functions.h(5): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\\projects\\functions.h(5): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
```

Comment: Obviously _something_'s different, and it's doubtful we can see what that is from here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the namespace in front of wstring in the header

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <vector>

extern void split(const std::wstring &s, WCHAR c, std::vector<std::wstring>& v);
```

Also good to add a guard so that when included it is not included multiple times. (`#pragma once`)

Comment: Thank you! Solved. Question - what do you mean by not included multiple times?

Comment: The pragma once will prevent the header from being included several times. E.g. if you have two files that include the header and include both those files it only gets included once.